# Using numpy for polynomial fit on pandas dataframe

Tags: numpy, dataframe, statsmodels, data-fitting

I have a dataframe containing astronomical data:

[image]

I'm using `statsmodels.formula.api` to try to apply a polynomial fit to an dataframe, using columns labelled `log_z` and `U`, `B`, `V`, and other variables. I've got so far

```
sources['log_z'] = np.log10(sources.z)
mask = ~np.isnan((B-I)) & ~np.isnan(log_z)
model = ols(formula='(B-I) + np.power((U-R),2) ~ log_z', data = [log_z[mask], (B-I)[mask]]).fit()
```

but I keep getting

```
PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
(B-I) + np.power((U-R),2) ~ log_z
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

even though I'm passing arrays into the function. I get the same error message (apart from the last line) no matter what arrays I use, or how I format them. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First, you have to make sure you specify which `ols` you are using. I am assuming it's `statsmodels.formula.api.ols`. Second, are you sure you can pass masked arrays into `ols`? Also where does `B` `log_z` and `I` variables are coming from? Did you use them to create the data frame? 
Finally, I think you should be using `dropna` method of Pandas DataFrame with `axis=0` so that all the rows which contain NaN/nan/NA etc. drops before you do any OLS. It has the same effect as masking when it comes to OLS and much safer

Comment: Thanks for that guidance. Yes, I'm using `statsmodels.formula.api`. I've used `sources.dropna(axis=0)` to drop the rows. I'll edit the question to reflect your comments.

Comment: Great! Thanks for updating the question. Here's the other thing. `dropna` has an argument called `inplace`. The default value is `False` that means it will create a new array which you should be storing in a different variable. Alternatively you can choose that to be `True` if you don't care about `sources` variable being updated. Finally, I see a lot of `-999.000` values there which is detrimental for OLS. If you want to treat them as NA, you can use the [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function to replace them with na before drop.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `fillna` method. The docs at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html, and the articles I found at


https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/12-pandas-techniques-python-data-manipulation/

https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_missing_data/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-fillna-to-replace-null-values-in-dataframe/

 say that I can use it to replace a `NaN` with another value, but how do I tell it to change `-999` to `NaN`?

Comment: I also tried `sources.replace(-999, np.nan)`, but it had no effect.

Comment: That's probably because they are not -999 square but something like -999 - eps with eps being a very small negative number. Depending on your application, if you know that anything less than -999 is actually a missing variable, what you can do is `sources.loc[sources[["U","V","B",]] < -999, ["U","V","B",]] = np.nan` and then run `dropna`. `fillna` works the opposite of what you are looking for so sorry for misleading you.